# Flatten a nested list of strings into a single string

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists

I am trying to convert a list of list into a single string using python and I don't want to use any loops I want to do it using lambda in Python but not getting the desired result.
here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import math
from functools import reduce
def collapse(L):
    list = lambda L: [item for sublist in L for item in sublist]
    #sum(L, [])
    #print('"',*list,sep=' ')
    #whole_string = ''.join(list).replace(' ')
l=[ ["I","am"], ["trying", "to", "convert"], ["listoflist", "intoastring."]]
collapse(l)
print(*l,sep='')
```

I want an output like this "I am  trying to convert listoflist intoastring."

Comment: @Martjin Pieters It is not completely a duplicate. He forgot to `return` from `collapse`, to reassign after it, and doesn't know how to use a lambda. The title is misleading.

Comment: @JulienD I realised that.... It's in my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding the use of the string operations in the sense that *none* of them work in-place. The original string is *not* modified, because strings are immutable. You will need to have your function return a value, and then assign the return value back to the original.

Here's a solution using `itertools.chain` (you can do it other ways too, this is just concise):

```
from itertools import chain

def collapse(lst):
    return ' ' .join(chain.from_iterable(lst))

out = collapse([["I","am"], ["trying", "to", "convert"], ["listoflist", "intoastring."]])
print(out)
```

---

```
'I am trying to convert listoflist intoastring.'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
>>> l=[ ["I","am"], ["trying", "to", "convert"], ["listoflist", "intoastring."]]
>>> 
>>> ' '.join([data for ele in l for data in ele])
'I am trying to convert listoflist intoastring.'
```

Its working for me

Comment: tried this inside function but not working

Comment: Sorry, but don't blatantly copy artefacts from my answer.